# Second loop not assigning proper END

Tags: bash

I have a script that will create 3 files.

keyword1script.sh

keyword2script.sh

keyword3script.sh

In each file i would like to see the following

```
cat keyword1script.sh
filekeyword11
filekeyword12
filekeyword13
filekeyword14

cat keyword2script.sh
filekeyword11
filekeyword12
filekeyword13
filekeyword14
filekeyword15
filekeyword16

cat keyword3script.sh
filekeyword11
filekeyword12
```

How ever what I am getting:

```
cat keyword1script.sh
filekeyword11
filekeyword12
filekeyword13
filekeyword14

cat keyword2script.sh
filekeyword11
filekeyword12
filekeyword13
filekeyword14

cat keyword3script.sh
filekeyword11
filekeyword12
filekeyword13
filekeyword14
```

I have tried changing some parts of the code around and different types of looping however all yield the same result.

```
#!/bin/bash

findwords=( keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 )
files=( 4 7 2 )

for t in "${findwords[@]}"
do
END=( "${files[@]}" )
  for i in $(seq 1 $END)
  do
  echo "" >> ${t}script.sh
  echo "file${t}$i" >> ${t}script.sh
  done
done
```

The first loop seems to working fine, files keyword1script.sh, keyword1script.sh, and keyword1script.sh are created however each file contains the same amount of rows.

The `END` variable should change once the first loop is done to the second number in the array files.

Comment: Try running the script under `set -xv` to see what's going on.

Comment: `t` is a string.  `files` is not an associative array.  So `${files[t]}` is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you for pointing that out, I updated the question and changed END=( "${files[t]}" ) to END=( "${files[@]}" )  I have tried so many different things I am going in circles.